# One-to-one mapping with Fluent NHibernate not working

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent, mappings

I have 2 tables (Labour and LabourPosition). Instead of having a fki to the LabourPosition table from the Labour table, I'd like to use an object `(theLabourer.LabourPosition.Name`instead of `getLabourPosition(theLabourer.LabourPositionId)`.

I've read a few articles to do this but they don't seem to be working for me... the error I get when trying to view the value of the LabourPosition property is "Could not initialize proxy - no Session".

My mapping (p.s: LabourPosition does not have a fki back to Labour, one way only):
LabourMap class:

```
References<LabourPosition>(x => x.LabourPosition, "LabourPositionsId");
```

And then obviously I've defined the property in the Labour entity as:

```
public virtual LabourPosition LabourPosition { get; set; }
```

Any ideas? Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [fluent mapping](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Fluent_mapping) documentation

> HasOne / one-to-one
>
> HasOne is usually reserved for a special case. Generally, you'd use a
>   References relationship in most situations (see: I think you mean a
>   many-to-one). If you really do want a one-to-one, then you can use the
>   HasOne method.
>
> HasOne(x => x.Cover);

If you want to use a reference (as your code suggests), you need to map both sides of the relationship.  From the documentation:

> HasMany / one-to-many
>
> HasMany is probably the most common collection-based relationship
>   you're going to use. HasMany is the "other side" of a References
>   relationship, and gets applied on the "one side" (one author has many
>   books). Now let's map the author side of the relationship we started
>   above. We need to join into the books table returning a collection of
>   any books associated with that author.
>
> public class Author {   public IList Books { get; set; } } We
>   use the HasMany method in the AuthorMap constructor to map this side
>   of the relationship:
>
> HasMany(x => x.Books); As with References, the foreign-key defaults to
>   Author_id, and you can override it with the KeyColumn method or change
>   the default behaviour with a Convention.
>
> There are a few different types of collections you can use, and
>   they're all available under the HasMany call.

Why do you need a one-one relationship, instead of just keeping all the columns in a single table?

Answer (score 0):

In your mapping try

```
References(x => x.LabourPosition, "LabourPositionsId");
```